# Change image on mouse over with CSS not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using CSS, I would like an image/link that changes as the mouse moves over it. I don't understand why the code below is not working. `@user.twitter` does have a value. Since the link has no text, only an image, I'm a bit uncertain what to place as the first value behing the brackets. As it stands, no image at all shows up on the screen. What is wrong with the code below?

Html code:

```
<%= link_to("", @user.twitter, :class => "twitter") %>
```

CSS:

```
.twitter {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: image-url('twitter.png');
}
.twitter:hover {
  background: image-url('twitter_.png');
}
```

Update: If I check the page's source code it is:

```
<a class="twitter" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/z1u2n2e2/

Comment: Did you check the generated anchor element ? It might have something to do with using `@user.twitter` as the url. You said it has a value, but what kind of value.

Comment: `@user.twitter` has a string as a value, but given the update added to the OP I think this is working correctly.

Comment: Okay. Does the link point to the user's twitter page or image ?

Comment: It points to the user's twitter page (or any url basically). But see answer of Paulie_D; that seems to go in the right direction.

Comment: Alright then :), I just wanted to point out that you need to use `image_tag` inside the block you give to `link_to` to properly add an image as a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without a demo with the **actual HTML & CSS** but your CSS is slightly malformed.

Also, the link would need to be `inline-block` or `block` rather than the default `display:inline`

```css
.twitter {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HkpT3JSkNWA/Txcu2eo0A-I/AAAAAAAAAlY/0eUq2M85Px8/s000/twitter.png);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
.twitter:hover {
  background-image: url('http://www.easychirp.com/images/share/twitter.png');
}
```

```html
<a class="twitter" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `background-image` and `url` instead of `image-url` had no effect.

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block`

Comment: Yes, now it is showing up. Only problem is that only part of the image shows up (part of the image is cut-off), while I would expect width and height to stretch the image to those dimensions...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my CSS:

```
.twitter {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url('twitter.png');
}
.twitter:hover {
    background-image: url('twitter-hover.png');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `url` and `background-image` instead of `image-url` had no effect.

Comment: check Image url(path) and image size .

Comment: The path/image is correct; if I just show the image using `image_tage` it shows up correctly.

Comment: img tag is html tag but here we are using css both are different.

Comment: Yeah, but it proofs the path is correct and that the image is not 0x0 in size, which is what I understoof you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
.twitter {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('twitter.png') no-repeat;
}
.twitter:hover {
    background: url('twitter_.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `url` and `no-repeat` instead of `image-url` had no effect.

Comment: set background-size:25px 25px;